# Issues while setting up automatic pull request using GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to make this action work, but I'm confused also what's it's missing in between, while triggering the peter-evans PR.

The scenario is simple, i want a PR to automatically created to the "main" branch whenever a new change is coming to the feature branch "testBranch"

```yaml
name: Create production pull request
on:
  push:``your text``
    branches:
      - testBranch
jobs:
  productionPR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: main
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5
        with:
          branch: main
```

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

The YAML you provided is close, but there are a few modifications needed. Here's the corrected configuration:

```yaml
name: Create production pull request
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - testBranch

jobs:
  productionPR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout main branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: main

      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Use the GitHub token to create the PR
          branch: testBranch
```

The token is automatically available in GitHub Actions and has the necessary permissions to create a pull request.

Make sure to add this YAML file to the `.github/workflows` directory in your repository.